# Data transformation for KendoUI grid

Tags: javascript, json, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a JSON data structure that I need to display in Kendo UI grid. The data is something like this

```
[
{"ObjType": {"Key1":"Value1", "Key2":"Value2", "Key3":["1234","45223"]}},
{"ObjType": {"Key1":"Value3", "Key2":"Value4", "Key3":["1234","45223"]}},
{"ObjType": {"Key1":"Value5", "Key2":"Value6", "Key3":["1234","45223"]}}
]
```

Kendo UI expects an array of Key/Value pairs or defined columns with array of arrays of values. What's the best way to transform this into something that the grid can understand?

Or maybe there is a way in Kendo grid to specify where to get the data from. The array in Key3 can be converted into string.

The schemas of the data can change - for different ObjType there will be different keys and different number of them, but the structure is pretty much the same - string key and string or array of strings value. And the ObjType stays the same through the document, but can change when we read a different document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Kendo UI DataSource **schema** has a `parse` configuration option, which allows you to tweak the data response before the DataSource instance handles it.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-schema.parse